# typoscript CONTENT table sys_language_uid=-1 no result

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to get my "cal" categories.

If i use the code below, i do not get any result, because the sys_language_uid of the categories is -1 (All languages).

If i change the sys_language_uid's to 0 (default language), i get my categories.

Where is the background for this?

```
lib.eventcategories = CONTENT
lib.eventcategories {
    table = tx_cal_category
    select {
        selectFields = uid
        pidInList = 47
   }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = uid
        10.noTrimWrap = |test: | - |
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [TS reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Select/Index.html#languagefield). Here you see that you can disable the language handling. With the following setting you can also activate the handling for "not default" language.